# Visual Basic Speech Recognition Examples?

Tags: vb.net, voice-recognition

I am looking for some good examples of Speech Recognition using VB. I am looking for recent examples, everything I have found is several years old. I am running Visual Studio 2010 with the most recent SDK. I was able to figure out text to speech but I am chasing my tail on speech to text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### VB-2010 Speech Recognition

---

Download the latest SAMPLES.zip for VS-2010 from here:

> **http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vb2010samples/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx**

It contains Speech Recognition sample as part of its Tablet-PC Samples.

> **http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vb2010samples#tablet**

I Hope it suits your purpose.

GoodLUCK!!
- CVS